# Open several new tabs in JavaScript and get immediate control

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

How can I prevent tab opening delay so that I regain control immediately after a single `window.open`?
Is there any  asynchronous `window.open` like instruction/function available?
Otherwise, how can I emulate the <kbd>Ctrl+click</kbd> behavior using Javascript?

… Given the following context …

I have a navigation bar that contains a lot of links pointing to different sections of the application.
One of the big bosses said: *«When I click on many of those links the application gets unresponsive»*
Which basically mean that he keeps on clicking on those links and then too many tabs suddenly open all at once.

The navigation bar contains links that when clicked trigger the following instruction: `window.open(LINK_ADDRESS_HERE, "_blank")`.
I have noticed that if let's say 6 of those links are clicked within like two seconds, related tabs open as I click on them. But clicking 10 different (navbar) links causes to delay tabs opening, and all of a sudden, the expected tabs finally open, but it takes 3 or more seconds for them to open.

I suspect the user to run too many clicks at the same time and the browser might not handle this.
On the other hand <kbd>Ctrl+click</kbd> several links (so they open in a new tab each) on some random sites like *StackOverflow* doesn't disturb the browser at all and tab opening is not delayed.

In my opinion the issue must come either from my application's JavaScript code or the way `window.open` works.
Tabs open successfully when only few links have been clicked. But if I click a lot more after the first set of links that have already loaded, at that point this may be either that the application is slow and it takes longer for the new tabs to load, or opened tabs that still load consume the available connections the browser tolerate for a single domain/application (I think that's like 6 connections in HTTP 1.1) and so when new calls to `window.open` are made, they just wait for a connection slot to be freed. As suche, what I perceive as slow open tabs is due to `window.open` waiting for available connections.

Thank you.

Comment: You could allow the button to be clicked only every N seconds after the current click. Otherwise not certain what you mean by "regain control"?

Comment: Sounds like your app is memory intensive and multiple instances of it are causing browser to bog down. Create a simple html page that does same window opening but with limited script in it and compare. Also try in different browser(s) and with extensions disabled

Comment: @guest271314 i thought of it, but it will keep being unresponsive or slow.
by regain control i mean since i suspect window.open is taking some time to open some tabs, i would like to make that call (window.open) and regain control immediately, like async calls, that no matter how they take, you always regain control immediately after you made them

Comment: @charlietfl  i think the application is not optimized at all in the frontend. so when you try to open to many tabs at once, it takes a more time for them to open since the frontend consumes too much connections, but im not sure

Comment: That's why a simple html page test would be a benchmark for you. Sounds like you need to do some profiling and optimizing